# Is it safe to alias mf command?

Tags: linux, bash, alias, mv

I routinely type `mf` instead of `mv`, and it doesn’t like to quit easily. I understand that `mf` is a metafont command, whatever that is.

Is it safe to `alias mf='mv'` so I don’t have to worry about it? Will it interfere with anything else?

Comment: Depends entirely what your goal is, which you don't state. As an example a lot of people prefer stricter workflows. Example: Vim allows to map keys so that cursor movement keys can be used instead of hjkl ... however, by doing so you start relying on _your_ `.vimrc` and may be lost on a system not prepared by you. This also holds for your `.bashrc`. So if your goal is to simply remove an annoyance, go ahead. But you could also install the package `sl` and alias `mf` to `sl` and enjoy a moment of contemplation whenever you mistype `mv` ... doing that often enough will create a learning effect.

Comment: You should probably try to get rid of that habit, instead of trying to work it around. How about an `alias mf='echo DONT PRESS mf again!!!'`.

Comment: @mosvy Nice idea. The question was really whether it was safe to alias `mf`, so that’s a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you never need to run `mf`, then yes, aliasing `mf` to `mv` is safe. Running `alias mf='mv'` manually will only affect the current shell, and running it in your interactive shell startup scripts (typically, `~/.bashrc` for Bash) will only change `mf` in your interactive shells.

Any program trying to run `mf` and expecting MetaFont won’t be affected by these changes.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I had hoped. I have added `alias mf='mv -i'` to `~/.bashrc`.